# "Smart" rewrite rule for basic web app

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I'm trying to create a regexp for my .htaccess with high amount of flexibility, I know my solution is not the best, but this is what I want for the specific project.

So.

/website is my base and .htaccess currently look like:

```
RewriteRule    ^([A-Za-z0-9-]+)/$    index.php?page=$1&$2    [NC,L]
```

This works fine aslong as I am visiting /website/anypagename pages. What I want to do next is ?to=allow&getquery=strings and fetch them with $_GET in php, but the .htaccess won't let me.

I also want my .htaccess to allow ANY /-urls where the structure would look like:

```
/website/pagename/z1/x1/z2/x2/z3/x3
```

where z1 is a name of a `$_GET` variable, and x1 is its value. Of course normal get arguments shall work aswell.

However I tweak it I can't get it to do what I want. Also, with the z1/x1 structure - will I be able to visit physical files or even load css?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule "^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)(/.*)?$" /$1$4?$2=$3 [L,QSA]

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ /index.php?page=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: Thank you for your time and help mr anubhava!

The first three lines of .htaccess code works properly! Changed (.+?) a bit though.

Regarding my other request, if I add the line you wrote it "takes over" the first / after /website so that, example:
/website/mypage/var/value makes ['mypage'] = 'var'. The following slashes are not included either. Any thoughts?

Comment: Ah sorry, was my first post on stackoverflow :)